# How to validate a field using cq.HTTP.post method In adobe cq5?

Tags: validation, post, extjs, dialog, aem

I am trying to validate a field by sending field value to a servlet and in response i'm getting true or false i.e whether this field is valid or not . here is my dialog file

```
  <bodytext
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            fieldDescription="Type Text Here"
            fieldLabel="Body Text"
            name="./bodytext"
     validator= "function(value) {   
var dialog = this.findParentByType('dialog');  
var postParams = {};
postParams['value'] = value;
```

CQ.HTTP.post('/bin/feeds/validation.json', function(options, success, response){response.valid ? true : 'Form name already exists on this page.';},postParams);
  }"
                xtype="textarea"/>

and here is my servlet code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.io.JSONWriter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.day.cq.commons.TidyJSONWriter;

public abstract class AbstractValidatorServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractValidatorServlet.class);


    @Override
    protected final void doPost(final SlingHttpServletRequest request, final SlingHttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String value = request.getRequestParameter("value").getString();
       final boolean valid = isValid(value);      
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");


        try {
            final TidyJSONWriter writer = new TidyJSONWriter(response.getWriter());
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            //JSONWriter writer = new JSONWriter(response.getWriter());
                    try {
                    writer.object();
                    writer.key("valid").value(valid);
                    writer.endObject(); 

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }  catch (final IOException ioe) {
            LOG.error("error writing JSON response", ioe);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validate the given value for this request and path.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param path path to current component being validated
     * @param value input value to validate
     * @return true if value is valid, false otherwise
     */
    protected abstract boolean isValid(final String value);

}



import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.w3c.tidy.Tidy;

import com.adobe.granite.xss.XSSAPI;

@Component
@Service
@Properties({
    @Property(name="sling.servlet.paths",value="/bin/feeds/validation"),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.extensions", value = "json"),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = "POST"),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.selectors", value = "validator"),
    @Property(name = "service.description", value = "XSS API HTML Validator Servlet")
})
public final class HTMLValidatorServlet extends AbstractValidatorServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HTMLValidatorServlet.class);

    @Reference
    XSSAPI xssapi;

    @Override
    protected boolean isValid(final String value) {
            String data = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">"
                    + "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><title></title><body>"+StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(value)+"</body></html>";

            Tidy tidy=new Tidy();
            tidy.setXmlTags(true); 
            tidy.setXHTML(true);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); 
            tidy.setErrout(new PrintWriter(writer)); 
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes()); 
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            tidy.parse(in,out); 
            int numErrors = tidy.getParseErrors();
            if(numErrors > 0) 
            { 
                return false;
            }
            else{
            return true;
            }
    }

}
```

I'm getting aUnspecified Error in cq5. can anybody where i'm lacking . thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since the post doesn't mention the imports , I'm assuming you are  using the Citytech Bedrock library's  [AbstractValidatorServlet](http://code.citytechinc.com/bedrock/apidocs/com/citytechinc/aem/bedrock/core/servlets/AbstractValidatorServlet.html#isValid(org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). This servlet only overrides the doGet method. The [docs](http://code.citytechinc.com/bedrock/apidocs/com/citytechinc/aem/bedrock/core/servlets/AbstractValidatorServlet.html) say the servlets have to be registered to a resourceType and GET method.

> @SlingServlet(resourceTypes = "bedrock/components/content/example",
>   selectors = "validator",  extensions = "json", methods = "GET")

The library also have a javascript utility method to call the validator servlet

> Bedrock.Utilities.Dialog.validateField(this, value, 'Name is
>   invalid');

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually that the servlet is expecting a json extension and you are sending none. Look closely at the following definition:

```
@Property(name = "sling.servlet.extensions", value = "json")
```

and in your JS function you are calling the url /bin/feeds/validation:

```
CQ.HTTP.post('/bin/feeds/validation', function(options, success, response){}
```

So change the url to /bin/feeds/validation.json and it should work.
Beside this you are expecting json and you are generating a html output.
For building json response, you can use the class com.day.cq.commons.TidyJSONWriter as follows:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(final SlingHttpServletRequest request, final SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final TidyJSONWriter writer = new TidyJSONWriter(response.getWriter());
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    try {
        writer.object();
        writer.key("mykey").value("myvalue");
        writer.endObject();

    } catch(Exception e) {
      //handle the exceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the same mentioned by you but still having same error. should i show you my code?

Comment: I looked again into the signature of your servlet. I'm not familar with the class AbstractValidatorServlet, but if it is the [one](http://code.citytechinc.com/bedrock/apidocs/com/citytechinc/aem/bedrock/core/servlets/AbstractValidatorServlet.html) mentioned in the post of @sharath-madappa than from the javadoc, you will see that it is extending the SlingSafeMethodsServlet which supports only GET requests. You can either change the signature of you class to extend SlingAllMethodsServlet and override the doPost method or change the js call to perform GET instead of POST.

Comment: i changed it also now i'm not getting error but it is not validating it and getting unspecified error pop up in cq5

Comment: You are still using sling.servlet.methods POST instead of your implemented GET, please change that value. If you want to use POST request than you need extend the SlingAllMethodsServlet and override the doPost() method. Please look at the docs for SlingSafeMethodsServlet:  "Please note, that this base class is intended for applications where data is only read. As such, this servlet by itself does not support the POST, PUT and DELETE methods". Beside this your validation url,still do not end with .json. Please read my comments before carefully.

Comment: i did that but didn't update the code here.. i update it now.. still m getting unspecified error

Comment: Your original question was heavely changed and helped you through in order to resolve it (you can now call the servlet and you get a response). I suggest that you open new question by providing full information of what the problems is (with stacktrace) and specify exactly where the problem occurs. Unspecified error, do not sound like a java related problem. If you are on the same opinion, than please mark this answer as accepted and put a link to the new question.